# repeat process until a condition is met

Tags: php, mysql, while-loop, iteration, do-while

I am trying to check for common students among courses to be assigned and courses already assigned to timeslots.

```
$chkcommsa = mysql_query("
    SELECT student.matric, student.std_name FROM student
    JOIN course_reg e1 ON e1.matric=student.matric
    JOIN course c1 ON c1.course_code=e1.course_code
    JOIN course_reg e2 ON e2.matric=student.matric
    JOIN course c2 on c2.course_code = e2.course_code
    WHERE c1.course_code = '".$currentass."' AND c2.course_code RLIKE '%$docamat%'
    GROUP BY student.matric") or die(mysql_error());

$num_rowea = mysql_num_rows($chkcommsa);

if($num_rowea >= 1) {

    $t_slot_times = $t_slot_time + 1;

}
```

If `$t_slot_times` is 2, query checks for common students between current course($currentass) to be assigned and all other courses(`$docamat`) already assigned to timeslot 2, if common students, system increment the timeslot by one to 3.

If `$t_slot_times` is 3, I want the system to check again for common students between the new course to be assigned and other courses already assigned to timeslot 3. I just want the a repetition of the query on `$t_slot_times` until the query returns 0 result.

Comment: for(i=0;i<=slottimes;i++)  { `run_your_query_code` }  ?..

Answer (score 0):

As per your question use the below logic and add your query inside the loops that you wish to add if  $t_slot_times is 2  and when  $t_slot_times is 3

```
if($num_rowea >= 1) {
    $t_slot_times = $t_slot_time + 1;

    for ($i = 1;$i<=20;$i++)
    {
      //code here
     }

}
```

Comment: Thanks but $t_slot_times is not just 2 and 3, it can change to anything randomly between 1-20 based on previous instructions within the entire code. Also do u mean i have to repeat the query again within the loop after using placing it before this if($num_rowea >= 1) {

Comment: Pls note that the new '$t_slot_times' is use in this query below to fetch the courses already assigned to it, these courses are stored in '$docama' which is to be used in our old query in the initial question. '$queuen = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM put_exam WHERE sess_id ='".$t_slot_times."'") or die(mysql_error());


$arrDatasa= array();

  while($rowsa = mysql_fetch_array($queuen)) 
  { 
    $arrDatasa[]=$rowsa['course_code']. '|';
 $docam = array_filter($arrDatasa);
  }
  
 foreach($arrDatasa as $a=> $rowsa){
 $docama.=$docam[$a];
} '

Comment: @Yommy, check my updated answer now you can do anything till 20 loops, you can replace that 20 with dynamically bought value.